# Showing that the metric $d(n, m) = 2^{-r}$ if $|n - m| = 2^{r}t$ with $t$ odd if $n \neq m$ and $d_2(n, n) = 0$ on $\mathbb Z$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I'm looking at some old question papers and here's a problem:

> If $n$ and $m$ are integers and $d(n, m) = 2^{-r}$ if $|n - m| = 2^{r}t$ with $t$ odd if $n \neq m$ and $d_2(n, n) = 0$. Prove that the metric space $(\mathbb Z, d)$ is not complete. (Hint: Consider the sequence $a_n = \frac{4^{n} - 1}{3}$.)

The given hint doesn't really make sense to me, as every element of the form $a_n = \frac{4^n - 1}{3}$ can be [shown to be odd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416674/proving-that-2n-1n-over-3-is-an-odd-number-for-all-n-ge1). Then the distance between any two elements of $(a_n)$ would be $2^{-0} = 1$ according to the given metric $d(\cdot, \cdot)$. So this is not even a Cauchy sequence in $(\mathbb Z, d)$.

**Edit**: I realized that this is incorrect, after seeing the comments. $(a_n)$ is indeed a Cauchy sequence -- one should consider the difference between the elements of $(a_n)$.

Is there any other sensible Cauchy sequence that I can use to prove that this metric on $\mathbb Z$ is not complete?

Comment: Yes, but what is $d(a_n,a_m)?$ You need a Cauchy sequence which doesn't converge.

Comment: In fact, you are describing the well-known dyadic or (2-adic) metric. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) for p-adic numbers in general.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, you're right. I should consider the distance between the elements which is of the form $4^mt$ where $t$ is an odd integer. Indeed, this distance gets smaller as we move along the tail of the sequence. What do you suggest to check that the sequence doesn't converge to an integer?

Comment: Show that if $a_n$ converges to an integer $a,$ than $3a_n$ converges to $3a,$ and then show that $4^n-1$ converges to $-1.$

Comment: How big is the integer to which this sequence converges, if there is such a thing?

Comment: @IgorRivin That doesn't work, at least not obviously. $2^n$ converges to $0,$ for example. "Big" is not much of a useful concept in this metric.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But it is a useful concept in the Archimedean metric. We have limit $l$ such that $|l - (4^n-1)/3)|$ goes to zero, so the difference is divisible by a large power of two, which means that the difference is at least as large as that power of 2 (that is exactly the point of subtracting the $1$ and dividing by $3.$

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. There is an explanation for a more general version of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/497788). The context is indeed that of $p$-adic metrics on $\mathbb Z$ not being complete.

Comment: @IgorRivin We are explicitly in a non-archimedian metric.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are not understanding what I said.